# Раздача видео с использованием Qt и OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv

Я написал модуль с использованием OpenCV и Qt, который делает следующее: читает видео из rtmp-канала и обрабатывает его покадрово, добавляя дополнительные надписи и другие элементы. Вопрос: как мне отдавать наружу мой модернизированный видеопоток, например, по rtmp?

Comment: С помощью [RTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) :)

Comment: @Cerbo, спасибо за всеобъемлющий ответ

Comment: можно это написать на ffmpeg. Нужно только сделать как модуль код, который добавляет надписи и прочье.